# IIS7.5 : m4v is not delivered on iphone

Tags: iphone, iis, mime-types, m4v

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.
I added this mime-type for my website: .m4v video/m4v.
My webpage is using html5  tag with an m4v format video file.
My problem is i can't see the video on my iPhone. I get an error : "video couldn't be loaded either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported"

If I open the video on iPhone (without using an url), I can read it. Besides, I installed the video on an Apache server and it  can be played properly.
So I suppose the video is correct but IIS doesn't deliver the proper format file.

I tried several other mime types, service and server restart but I can't get the video on the webpage on iPhone. Static content compression is on (same problem when i set it off).
Any idea on how to manage this?
Thank you.